# How to embed a line-chart from a logfile?

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

I have a logfile `progress.txt` in the format

```
<epoch> <space> <number> <space> <rest...>
```

Here an example excerpt:

```
$ cat progress.txt 
1375097557 40 523 3927 26884
1375162528 40 529 3939 26969
1375170979 44 630 4761 32536
1375171815 44 637 4822 32965
....
```

I would like to have LaTeX to render a **line-chart** with *x-axis* from *column-1* and *y-axis* from *column-2*. The *column-1* is in *seconds since 1970* format, but this is not that important because I don't need any *x-axis*-labeling.

The chart would look like this, then:

```
|               -----
|             --
|       ------  
|-------       
|
+-----------------------
```

If simple enough, **without external reprocessing**, although it would not be a big problem, because I use a `Makefile` anyway.

**An extension** would be to use *column-5* on a **secondary y-axis**, then both drawn in different colors or styles, i.e.

```
|             °°-----   :
|       °°°°°°--        :
|      °------          :
|-----°-                :
|°°°°°                  :
+-----------------------+
```

I use

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

anyway, so a *TikZ*-solution is preferred.

Comment: Do you know [`pgfplots`](http://www.ctan.org/pkgs/pgfplots)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Ignasi said, you could use PGFPlots for this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents}{progress.txt}
1375097557 40 523 3927 26884
1375162528 40 529 3939 26969
1375170979 44 630 4761 32536
1375171815 44 637 4822 32965
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{
    scale only axis, % helps with aligning the two axes
    x filter/.code={
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult-1.375e9} % centering the data
    }
}

\begin{axis}[   % First curve, left axis
    axis y line*=left,
    xtick=\empty
]
\addplot [black] table {progress.txt};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[   % Second curve, right axis
    hide x axis,
    axis y line*=right,
    yticklabel style=red
]
\addplot [thick, red] table [y index=3] {progress.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I have to copy/paste the data into the `\begin{filecontents}` section (manually, or by script) or can I access the file directly. If I leave out that section (hoping that `\addplot ... {progress.txt};` will read it` fails with "dimension too large". I don't see any invalid data in the file. Oops no, I also get that error when pasting the contents. Hrmm....

Comment: @towi: No, you don't have to copy/paste the data, that's just for the example. Could you edit your question to include a bit more data that triggers the error?

Comment: I am closer now. It seems to be the calculated x-values. If I put `\pgfmathparse{5}` in it I get a nice vertical line. Also, the error message is `[62] (./latex/98progress.tex
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@xa 
l.15 \addplot [black] table {progress.txt};`. I tried `{(\pgfmathresult-1.375e9)/86400}`, same error. Also, I reduced the data to the 4 lines I showed.

Comment: @towi: You get that error message when you compile the code exactly as I posted it?

Comment: Yes, I just created a new file `try.tex`. `$ latex try.tex ... (/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex)))
LaTeX Warning: File progress.txt already exists on the system. Not generating it from this source.
(./try.aux) ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgfmath@xa 
                            
l.24 \addplot [black] table {progress.txt};

No pages of output.` I will play around with the x-axis-formula. Oh, well removing the `x filter...` produces a nice picture in `try.tex`, but not in my project. Still looking...

Comment: Removing `x filter...` works. I will educate myself about how it works and will debug it over time. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With *pgfplots*, which is closely related to *TikZ*, you can do it by putting two `axis` environments in a single plot:

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{myfile.txt}
097557 40 523 3927 26884
122528 40 529 3939 28969
140979 42 630 4761 30536
171815 44 637 4822 32965
\end{filecontents}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmajorticks=false,ytick pos=left]
        \addplot[jump mark left,blue] table[x index=0, y index=1] {myfile.txt};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}
    [   xmajorticks=false,
        ytick pos=right,
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd, fixed, /tikz/.cd},
        scaled y ticks = false,
        ymin=25000,
        ymax=33000,
    ]
        \addplot[jump mark left,red] table[x index=0, y index=4] {myfile.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]